# RecognizerIntent gives error after latest Google Search update

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, voice

I have implemented a continous speech recognizer using SpeechRecognizer. 
RecognitionListener generally goes to ERROR_NETWORK  (Error no 2) after onBeginningOfSpeech.
This occurs not every time but many times.
This behaviour started since last update of Google 4.1.24.1672412.arm update (12 January 2015)

```
protected class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener
{
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
    {
     }
    public void onError(int error)
    {
        if (mIsStreamSolo)
        {  // CAudioLibrary.unmute();
            mIsStreamSolo = false;
        }

        if(error == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK||error == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER)
        {
```

.....

I have examined logcat and found out that it gives many errors like this:
It is not my device specific, it gives the same error on my users devices also. Is there a problem on google site ? If I revert google update, it works without giving these errors.
Thank you in advance.

```
01-15 14:36:48.656    3012-3012/? D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController﹕
onDataActivity: direction=2 01-15 14:36:48.656    3012-3012/?
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster -
setNWBoosterIndicators(false) 01-15 14:36:48.656    3012-3012/?
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
01-15 14:36:48.691  32404-32409/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed
384K, 25% free 10740K/14260K, paused 10ms+3ms, total 40ms 01-15
14:36:48.871   5732-13019/? W/JavaNetConnection﹕ Failed to get
connection status.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.google.com/m/voice-search/down?pair=6239918a-dc45-4eea-ac6f-b9bf8de57ced
            at kxb.getInputStream(PG:228)
            at kxa.getInputStream(PG:210)
            at kxc.getInputStream(PG:25)
            at cla.Gj(PG:256)
            at dzz.Gj(PG:26)
            at cla.Gi(PG:240)
            at cla.disconnect(PG:132)
            at clb.b(PG:110)
            at clb.a(PG:66)
            at dzb.a(PG:197)
            at cqj.HS(PG:529)
            at cqi.run(PG:314) 01-15 14:36:48.871   5732-13019/? W/S3NetworkUtils﹕ [Download] response code: 400, internal error
header: -74061 01-15 14:36:49.071   5732-13104/? W/JavaNetConnection﹕
Failed to get connection status.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.google.com/m/voice-search/down?pair=af1df3dc-08ac-45fd-bb30-eee3393bcb9c
            at kxb.getInputStream(PG:228)
            at kxa.getInputStream(PG:210)
            at kxc.getInputStream(PG:25)
            at cla.Gj(PG:256)
            at dzz.Gj(PG:26)
            at cla.Gi(PG:240)
            at cla.disconnect(PG:132)
            at clb.b(PG:110)
            at clb.a(PG:66)
            at dzb.a(PG:197)
            at cqj.HS(PG:529)
            at cqi.run(PG:314) 01-15 14:36:49.071   5732-13104/? W/S3NetworkUtils﹕ [Download] response code: 400, internal error
```

Also, I have noticed following lines:

> 01-15 14:36:55.556    5732-6800/? W/EventLogger﹕ recordGsaError
>       eyd: tr-TR
>               at hdv.a(PG:121)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at fid.run(PG:102)
>               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 01-15 14:36:55.556    5732-6800/? W/ErrorProcessor﹕ onFatalError, ignoring
>   error from engine(1): eyd: tr-TR 01-15 14:36:55.556    5732-6800/?
>   W/EventLogger﹕ recordGsaError
>       eyb: GsaErrorCode: 458756, engine: 1
>               at hdv.a(PG:126)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at fid.run(PG:102)
>               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 01-15 14:36:55.556    5732-6800/? W/DefaultRecognitionState﹕ Repeated error
>   from secondary engine. 01-15 14:36:55.556    5732-6800/?
>   W/ErrorProcessor﹕ onFatalError, ignoring error from engine(1): eyb:
>   GsaErrorCode: 458756, engine: 1

Comment: Are you ducking the audio anywhere in your code or requesting audio focus?

Comment: I am reducing volume in some parts of the code but I think it is not the cause because when I change EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL to "en-US", it works without problem maybe it uses offline model when it is set to English. But I want to use Turkish local and when I set it to "tr-TR", it gives NETWORK_ERROR many times but not everytime. It is annoying issue. When I uninstall google search latest update it doesn't give any error.

Comment: I think it is a bug of Google Latest update because there are some bug report at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=100389 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=98005

Comment: Did you somehow fix your problem? I have the same issue....

Comment: No not yet, I tried a lot of combination. But I think this must be fixed on the google site. Please share your solution if you can find it also.Thank you.

Comment: Try removing all code where you alter the audio, either ducking it or requesting focus. This is the cause of a similar bug in their latest release, but it may be the same. Let me know.

Comment: I think Google fixed this issue. I haven't received any error since yesterday.. If so, this bug is fixed now.

Comment: UPDATE: The error continues sometimes but not as frequent as before.