# Android SpeechRecognizer stops suddenly Network Error

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, voice

THe code i'm using below has been used for over a year now with no problems. Google releases an update to the Google app and now when speechrecognizer gets called it almost immediately stops and returns "Network Error".  I uninstall the update from 1/12/15 and all works perfect again.  Anybody else experience this?? I haven't seen any comments on it yet so I may be the only one affected.  Please take a look at the code and tell me what I may be doing wrong.

```
sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this.getApplicationContext());
sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());

Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, prefCommandKey.toString());
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, prefLanguage);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
sr.startListening(intent);
```

The strange part is once in a great while it will let me record something then when I get to the next step it exits out when initiating the speechrecognizer again.  ANy help?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you requesting audio focus or ducking the audio anywhere else in your code, around the time you are executing this?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same  problem since the last update and  I     am sure that there is a bug in the Last Update.  I  have similar thread at [RecognizerIntent gives error after latest Google Search update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964043/recognizerintent-gives-error-after-latest-google-search-update)

In summary the error is
W/JavaNetConnection﹕ Failed to get
connection status.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.google.com/m/voice-search/down?pair=6239918a-dc45-4eea-ac6f-b9bf8de57ced

Edit: I think Google fixed this issue. I haven't received any error since yesterday.. If so, this bug is fixed now. –

Comment: This is not an answer

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem.  My problem at least.  I found that I was using the locale "en" for English and as soon as I changed it to "en-us" everything worked again.